# С# MySql при добавлении в "textbox" "/" - ошибка

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

создал хранимую процедуру:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_stock (IN _name varchar(250),IN _description varchar(500), IN _conditions varchar(500), IN _price double, IN _photo varchar(250))
BEGIN
insert into employee values(_name, _description, _conditions, _price, _photo);
SELECT * from stock;
END //
```

в phpmyadmin.

Подключил базу и пытаюсь добавить данные в базу, но при попытке добавить в базу текст, который начинается с "/" - ошибка: "Входная строка имела неверный формат".

Прикладываю код выполнения хранимой процедуры и скриншоты с ошибкой.

Код:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Connect();
    MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[5];
    parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameters[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
    parameters[1] = new MySqlParameter("_description", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameters[1].Value = textBox4.Text;
    parameters[2] = new MySqlParameter("_conditions", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameters[2].Value = textBox5.Text;
    parameters[3] = new MySqlParameter("_price", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameters[3].Value = textBox2.Text;
    parameters[4] = new MySqlParameter("_photo", SqlDbType.Text);
    parameters[4].Value = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
    command.Connection = con.cn;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "insert_stock";
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    con.cn.Open();
    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Комментарий пользователя: " + commentDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + " опубликован");
        command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `id_stock`, `name`, `description`, `conditions`, `price`, `photo` FROM `stock` WHERE 1", con.cn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dt = new DataTable();
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);
        commentDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Имя";
        commentDataGridView.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Описание";
        commentDataGridView.Columns[2].Width = 200;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Условия";
        commentDataGridView.Columns[3].Width = 300;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Цена";
        commentDataGridView.Columns[4].Width = 50;
        commentDataGridView.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Фото";
        commentDataGridView.Columns[5].Width = 105;
        commentDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        commentDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    }
    con.cn.Close();
}
```

Не работают вообще все символы!
P.s Рабочие поля сверху добавлял через саму базу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншоты ошибки!

Подробности исключения

```
 System.FormatException
      HResult=0x80131537
      Сообщение = Входная строка имела неверный формат.
      Источник = mscorlib
      Трассировка стека:
       в System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       в System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       в System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
       в System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
       в MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       в test1.stock.button14_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\alex\source\repos\test1\test1\stock.cs:строка 91
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       в test1.Authorization.bunifuButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\alex\source\repos\test1\test1\Authorization.cs:строка 33
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       в Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       в test1.Program.Main() в C:\Users\alex\source\repos\test1\test1\Program.cs:строка 19
    
      Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
        [Внешний код]
        test1.stock.button14_Click(object, System.EventArgs) в stock.cs
        [Внешний код]
        test1.Authorization.bunifuButton1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) в Authorization.cs
        [Внешний код]
        test1.Program.Main() в Program.cs
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка? `Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text)` - это преобразование строки в строку вообще зачем? Еще `IN _photo varchar(250)` и `SqlDbType.Text` как-то не стыкуются.

Comment: Ошибка в textBox3 - по какой причине не знаю. 
На скриншоте показал то, что мне выводит vs

Comment: Код на скрине и код, вставленный текстом - разные.

Comment: Это я уже экспериментировал. Изначально было везде varchar. Ошибка была та же

Comment: Если выполнить запрос напрямую без процедуры - все работает?

Comment: Да, так работает

Comment: И работает эта же процедура в phpmyadmin

Comment: Полную трассировку стека покажите у исключения

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);` при первом вызове обработчика вы добавляете в команду 5 параметров, при повторном еще 5, их становится 10. Я понимаю, что вы пока до повторного вызова не добрались, но обратите внимание, что команду надо пересоздавать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду знать.

Оставил подробности исключения в ответах

Comment: @aepot [работа программы](https://dropmefiles.com/oiotF)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но попробуй ввести без "/". У меня подозрения, что данный символ просто не поддерживается(или включен в список запрещенных") системой.